How are 413 requests handled by servers
I sent a search string to google that responded back with a 413 error stating that the request content is too large.
Also, I got back:
400. That’s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.

What does google, and servers in general, do with the body content of these invalid requests?
Does google save the content on separate servers for potential use in the future?
It is hard to imagine google discarding any data.

Of course they discard data that they cannot interpret. Everything else would be a waste of resources. If you sent a huge search string now and a week later they decide that the limit could be raised, what should they do with your search request? The connection is long gone, you're not waiting for results anymore.

@Hans-MartinMosner No, I meant that any data is always useful to google in some way. They can study it, research it, yada, yada.

@BearBileFarmingisTorture: don't get me wrong, but I guess your imagination goes here a little further than reality.

They actually send those requests to CIA and NSA, that stores it forever on their servers. They also feed it to their artificial intelligence to train it. It is a well known fact that they do it only for the requests that result in HTTP 413—everything else is discarded. By the way, all this is confidential, so don't tell anyone about it.

@ArseniMourzenko, and for added security and speed, the 413s are stored on tape drives and transported via station wagon to the NSA.

From a servers point of view, one main purpose of a "content too large" error is to limit the resource usage of the server by each client. So storing this "large" content, even if it just done in a log file, would obviously defeat that purpose and open a hole for a DOS attack (not necessarily an intentional one).
Hence, I would expect most sanely implemented servers to log just the attempt of such a request, and discard the content.
What specific server operators like Google do we cannot tell you, you have to ask them directly if you want to find out.*
*@Arseni Mourzenko seems to have some interesting ideas what Google does with that content, but I fear we won't find many references for that on the Web ;-).
